# CommunicationException while client's ctx.lookup() in GlassFish 3.1

Tags: java, serialization, glassfish, ejb

I have one entity class which implements Serializable and I got this error on client:

> javax.naming.CommunicationException:
>   Communication exception for
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl}
>   [Root exception is
>   java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA
>   BAD_PARAM 1398079494 Maybe; nested
>   exception is: 
>     java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
>   org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: WARNING:
>   IOP00100006: Class
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate
>   is not Serializable  vmcid: SUN  minor
>   code: 6 completed: Maybe

when I'm doing `SomeService serv = (SomeService)ctx.lookup("java:global/MyProject/SomeServiceImpl");`

Does Entity class should be in the same package both in server and in client?
Now Entity class is in the package (dir) of Client App and in the package (dir) where SomeService interface is on the server.

Answer (score 7):

I added `@Remote` annotation to service interface and error disapeared.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, I would have never figured this out from the error.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the following and everything works Ok.

When creating InitialContext as:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
```

And later,

```
myBeanService = (MyBeanService) ctx.lookup("java:global/AppName/MyBeanService");
```

Shows that exception, but if I just call this way:

```
myBeanService = (MyBeanService) new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/AppName/MyBeanService");
```

There is no problem. The problem are the JNDI properties.